# Module directory does not exist or cannot be read in Terraform

Tags: terraform-provider-azure, terraform-modules

I am trying to use Modules for dependencies in my Terraform code. But even after mentioning that particular source path in module, it gives an error “ Module directory  does not exist or cannot be read." and “Unable to evaluate directory – The system cannot find the file specified." Can anyone let me know what can be the reason.

I have to manage 3 different environments with 3 different backend state files for each environment. Here each main file calls the respective module file.The main folder consists of backend config, creation of resource group and it calls modules file

```
      root
        |
        |-- main 
        |    |--prod  
        |    |--dev    
        |    |--staging
        |-- modules
        |    |--prod   
        |    |--dev     
        |    |--staging
```

------------CODE-----------------

```
    provider "azurerm" {
    version = "=2.2.0"
   features {}
    }

    #--- CREATING RESOURCE GROUP PER ENVIRONEMENT
    terraform {
      backend "azurerm" {
        resource_group_name  = ""
        storage_account_name = ""
        container_name       = ""
        key                  = ""
        }
      }


    variable "location" {
      description           =   "Location for deployment of the Azure 
    resources"
   }

     variable "Code" {
       description           =   "Enter a unique two-letter ID to identify 
    customer resources; should match the DynamoDB table."
    }

     variable "EnvironmentType" {
       description       = "Enter a valid environment type. Valid values are 
     Prod, Dev, Staging"
      }

    variable "AccountType" {
      description   = "Select the type of account you wish to create. This 
       will determine which environments and other resources are created."
       }


     resource "azurerm_resource_group" "main" {
      name        = "${var.Code}-${var.EnvironmentType}"
      location    = "${var.location}"
     }

     module "ResourcesStack" {
        source                      = "./modules"
        AccountType                 = "${var.AccountType}"
        CustomerCode                = "${var.Code}"
        EnvironmentType             = "${var.EnvironmentType}"
        location                    = "${var.location}"
      }
```

Comment: Can you share the Terraform code that you use? And where the module you store is also necessary.

Comment: @CharlesXu i have added the structure of my files.

Comment: You need also to provide the Terraform code.

Comment: What do the pred and dev and staging mean? The different modules or the Terraform files?

Comment: According to the hierarchy, in the main folder, these are .tf files and in the modules folder they are different folders with required modules

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, with the communication and then I think you did the mistake when you quote the modules in the Terraform code.

The mistake is that when you want to quote the modules, you need to quote the special one. For example, you want to quote the module dev, then you can quote it in the Terraform code like this:

```
module "dev" {
  source      = "./modules/dev"
  ...
}
```

Do not set the module source with the root path of all the modules like you did.

Comment: i will check the source again.

Comment: It is still not working. I hope you know the prod, dev, staging inside module/main folder is not a .tf file. They are folders which contains the respective environment .tf file

Comment: @SiddhiMorajkar It should work. I double if you create the right modules and know how to use them. Take a look at the [Create Terraform modules](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/index.html). And you also need to create t.tf file in the modules to create resources.

Comment: I have created and refered the module correctly. Also now I have got another issue. Suppose i have a vnet.tf that creates virtual network and then calls the application gateway module, then it throws the error "Error: Virtual Network "aksVirtualNetwork" was not found ". I guess it does not create a vnet first.

Comment: @SiddhiMorajkar Can you share all the Terraform things you used? I cannot see them so that I cannot figure out what is the actual error.

Comment: Okay but that error is totally different from this issue

Comment: @SiddhiMorajkar If my answer solves this issue you meet?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210642/discussion-between-siddhimorajkar-and-charles-xu).

Comment: @SiddhiMorajkar Your reply is too late, I wait for almost a month. I think you need to reply quickly. Maybe you do not use the real path for your modules.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Terraform working directory in the Terraform cloud. The directory that Terraform will execute within. This defaults to the root of your repository and is typically set to a subdirectory matching the environment when multiple environments exist within the same repository. Add your module's path to [Terraform Working Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgF8g.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this symptom with quite an unexpected root cause. Using Terraform Cloud for state management, in the CI/CD tooling I construct the `credentials.tfrc.json` file, however, I had a typo causing the JSON to be invalid. Instead of reporting a validation error or 4xx status, the following was returned.

`The directory  could not be read for module`

> Note: there are no remote modules in this use case, all modules are local to the deploy time workspace.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing a similar issue recently, while running terraform in Automation (AWS code build)  Which brought me to this post. The script ran fine locally on my desktop but failed in automation may be because how it was packaged.

Initializing modules...

- **setup in**
- s3_agent in ../modules/s3
- s3_artifacts in ../modules/s3
  ╷
  │ Error: Unreadable module directory
  │
  │ Unable to evaluate directory symlink: lstat modules: no such file or
  │ directory
  ╵ Module directory  does not exist or cannot be read.

I noticed that the setup module highlighted above did not show the path to the module. It was only after hours that I realized that in the overall directory which had terraform scripts there were 2 folders with same name "**modules**" although at different folder hierarchy. It confused the Terraform to think that all modules are in 1 of the folder.

**Solution:** I renamed one of the folders which had setup module as module instead of "module**s**"

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -3):

Always make sure name of directory is **module** not modules.
I faced the same issue and after updating the directory name, it was resolved.

Comment: Examples in the official terraform documentation are showing it as "modules" directory not "module". Regardless it should not matter.